# How to use getter & setter using dependency injection?

Tags: php-7.1, symfony-4.4

I am trying to implement Dependency Injection in Symfony.

I created a class named Token as follows:

```
class Token
{
    private $token;
    private $key;

    public function __construct(string $key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->settoken();
    }

    public function getToken(): string
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    public function setToken(string $newString)
    {
        $token = $newString . '-' . $this->key;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

In the construct, I have a key which is defined in `services.yml`

Now I have injected this class into another controller like below.

```
$this->token->setToken('123456789');

dd($this->token->getToken())
```

But this is giving me 'Too few arguments to function setToken()' error. I think this is because in my Token class construct I have already passed key argument.

I am not sure how to properly use it.

Can anyone please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in the Token class. If you look at the __construct, you are calling to **$this->settoken()**

```
public function __construct(string $key)
{
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->settoken();
}
```

And below is the setToken method that has a string as a mandatory argument. That's why it gives you an error.

The class should look like this :

```
class Token {

private $token;
private $key;

public function __construct(string $key)
{
    $this->key = $key;
}

public function getToken(): string
{
    return $this->token;
}

public function setToken(string $newString): Token
{
    $this->token = $newString . '-' . $this->key;

    return $this;
}
```

}